# A bounded linear functional diverges when n $\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the Banach space $C(T)=\{f:[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}] \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \}$ with $f$ continuos with the uniform norm
\begin{equation*}
 ||f||= sup_{x \in [-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]} |f(x)|
\end{equation*}
For every $f \in C(T)$ define $\hat{f}(k)=\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-2 \pi i k x}f(x)dx$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and consider
\begin{equation*}
S_nf(x)=\sum_{k=-n} ^n \hat{f}(k)e ^{2 \pi k ix}
\end{equation*}
Take $x=0$ and define $T_n(f)=S_nf(0)$. I want to show that $||T_n|| \rightarrow \infty$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$. I already proved that $T_n$ is a bounded and linear functional in $C(T)$, i.e, I proved that $||T_n|| \leq 2nf$. I think about delimit that norm below with something that goes to infinity when $n \rightarrow \infty$ but I don't know what limit choose to do that.

Comment: Take $f(x)=\exp(2kπix)$, then $||f|| \leq 1$  and $ ||T_n|| =\sup \{ |T_n(g)| \colon ||g|| \leq 1  \} \geq |T_n(f)| = \sum_{k=-n}^n 1 \xrightarrow{n\to \infty} \infty$

Comment: in the definition of sup who is $g$? wouldn't it be $f$?

Comment: $g$ is an arbitrary element of $C(T)$. By definition, $||T_n||$ is the supremum of $|T_n(g)|$, taken over all functions $g$ with $||g||_\infty \leq 1$.

Comment: Ok, thank you @EvangelopoulosF.

Comment: @Evangelopoulos, what is $k$ in your example?

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake, sorry

Comment: $k$ is an integer. @EvangelopoulosF.

Answer (score 2):

Let us begin by analyzing the operators $S_n$,

**Theorem**.  $\|S_n\|\to\infty$, as $n\to\infty$.

*Proof*.
Notice that
$$
  S_nf(x)=
  \sum_{k=-n} ^n \hat{f}(k)e ^{2 \pi ikx} = $$$$ =
  \sum_{k=-n} ^n e ^{2 \pi ikx} \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-2 \pi i k y}f(y)\, dy =  $$$$ =
  \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}  \sum_{k=-n} ^n e ^{2 \pi ik(x-y)} f(y)\, dy.
  $$
In order to understand the above sum,
set $w=x-y$,  so
$$
  \sum_{k=-n} ^n e ^{2 \pi ik(x-y)} =
  \sum _{k=-n}^{n}e^{2\pi ikw} =  $$$$ =
  \frac{e^{-2\pi inw}-e^{2\pi inw}}{1-e^{2\pi iw}}  =
  {\frac {\sin \left(\left(2n+1\right)\pi w\right)}{\sin(\pi w)}}.
  $$
The function
$$
  D_n(w) =   {\frac {\sin \left(\left(2n+1\right)\pi w\right)}{\sin(\pi w)}}
  $$
is called the Dirichlet kernel and we have thus concluded that
$$
  S_nf(x)=
  \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}  D_n(x-y)f(y)\, dy.
  \tag 1
  $$
From this it follows that  $\|S_n\|$ coincides with the 1-norm
$$
  \|D_n\|_1 = \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} |D_n(w)|\, dw
  $$
of the Dirichlet kernel which is known to converge to infinity roughly as fast as $\log(n)$.  Thus the $S_n$ are unbounded.
QED

---

*Alternative Proof of same Theorem*.
Another proof, a bit more abstract, is as follows:  assume by contradiction that the $S_n$ are bounded.  Observing
moreover that

- $S_nf$ converges to $f$ for every trigonometric polynomial $f$,
- the trigonometric polynomials are dense in the subspace of $C([-1/2, 1/2])$ formed by the periodic functions,

we would be able to conclude that   $S_nf$ converges to $f$ for every continuos periodic function on $[-1/2, 1/2]$,
but this is known to be false, leading to a contradiction, so  the $S_n$ are unbounded.  QED

---

Addressing the norm of the functional
$T_nf:= S_nf(0)$,
observe that if $f$ is periodic,  then by extending $f$ to a periodic function on $\mathbb R$,  one has by (1)  that
$$
  S_nf(x-x_0)=
  \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}  D_n(x-x_0-y)f(y)\, dy = $$$$ =
  \int_{x_0-\frac{1}{2}}^{x_0+\frac{1}{2}}  D_n(x-y)f(y-x_0)\, dy = $$$$ =
  \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}  D_n(x-y)f(y-x_0)\, dy =
  S_n(\tau_{x_0}f)(x),
  $$
where  $\tau_{x_0}f(x) = f(x-x_0)$.  Plugging in $x=0$, and $x_0=-x$, we get
$$
  S_nf(x)=   S_n(\tau_{-x}f)(0) = T_n(\tau_{-x}f).
  $$

This said, we see that
$$
  \|S_nf\| =
   \sup_x |S_nf(x)|=
   \sup_x |T_n(\tau_{-x}f)| \leq
   \sup_x \|T_n\|\|\tau_{-x}f\| =
   \|T_n\|\|f\|,
  $$
so we see that $\|S_n\|\leq \|T_n\|$.  Since we know that $\|S_n\|$ is unbounded, it follows that $\|T_n\|$ is also unbounded.

Comment: Perhaps a shorter proof would be to pick up from (1) above, and notice that if we plug in $x=0$ there, then
  $$
  T_n(f) = S_nf(0)=
  \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}  D_n(-y)f(y)\, dy,
  $$
  so
  $\|T_n\| = \|D_n\|_1\to\infty$.